# nginx can't find cgi two levels deep

Tags: nginx, cgi

Typically, I want to serve an index.html file when `http://mysite.com/` and any other directory is requested. The following, in nginx.conf, does that for `/test`:

```
location /test {
    try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html /index.html =404;
}
```

If I want to serve files from that same location through cgi (on thttpd), this also works as it should, serving up a cgi programmed page:

```
location /test {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

The problem I have is figuring out how to go to a deeper level, such as /test/page1. If page1.html exists, I want that served but, if not, I want it to go to the thttpd server and run the cgi program there. The many variations in the config file I've tried either give me a redirect loop or file not found or an error from the server. Other times, I can get it to serve the cgi and html files but trying to access the directory gives a loop.

The following also worked, in part, but I'm so burned out trying different variations, I've gotten myself lost.

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/test;
}
```

I'm sure there is just one simple, fundamental thing I'm missing.

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files covers this quite nicely.

Comment: @BMDan Yes it does but it presumes PHP or filename extensions and nothing I've tried in that works.